# How to retrieve style of the HTML server control programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, servercontrols

Suppose i'm having `<div> tag with id="toggleText"  & runat="Server"` then i can change style attributes by using following -

```
toggleText.Style.Add("Display", "block");
```

But if i want to retrieve the style attribute then how to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy:

```
 toggleText.Style["Display"];
```

Answer (score 1):

When you query the control's [Style property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontrol.style.aspx) you get "a collection of all cascading style sheet (CSS) properties applied to a specified HTML server control in the ASP.NET file" - there's a code sample on that page as well.